# desktop does not come back after screen turns off

Tags: unity, suspend, samba, mdadm

after my screen goes to sleep, I move my mouse and try and wake the screen, I am just met with a black screen and the cursor.

I am able to ALT+CTRL+F3 to bash, and when I try and "startx" back into the desktop, i get an "X" cursor and no sidebar, or any options. the start key does not work either.

I am able to right click > terminal to reboot, but that gets very tiresome after a while.

What is going on? this is a pretty fresh install.

The only thing I've really done with this system is create a RAID1 disk using MDADM and set up samba shares to my home computers!

Otherwise this is a super fresh install!!!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your DM wasn't installed properly? I've come across similar situations whilst playing around with multiple DMs. The best solution I can think of is to restart the DM.

Bring up the terminal by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type in the command  `unity` (This is similar to the command `unity --replace`)

If you want to restart your entire X Session, then type in `sudo service sddm restart`

Hope this helps?

Comment: My DM? In the order of installed things on this OS is as follows. Ubuntu from the website. Samba share. Mdadm (for my raid) . I have not installed any additional guis or oses

Comment: My bad, I have assumed that you were running a Display Manager (DM).

Maybe you could try installing a DM like Gnome or Unity or if you don't want to, maybe you could check for the problem in your system/X logs present in the following locations 

`/var/log/syslog` or  `/var/log/Xorg.*.log` (where * is a number)